# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Following is the react code which is giving me error -

**Error -**

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Star`.

Code -

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { FaStar } from 'react-icons';

function Star() {
  return (
    <FaStar />
  )
} 

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Star Rating App</h1>
      <Star />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also tried writing `<Star />` component like -

```
const Star = () => {
  return (
    <FaStar />
  )
}
```

which is still giving the same error. Though if I move `<Star />` component to a separate file and import it in `App.js` file it works.

I am interested to know the reason behind this. Let me the concept around it.

Edit - CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-hawking-7br7g?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import it from the correct namespace, in this case [Font Awesome](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/icons?name=fa):

```
// Not 'react-icons'
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
```